# Show that if $f'_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of functions differentiable on $[a,b]$ with continuous derivatives and such that $f_n(x_1)$ converges for some point $x_1$ in $[a,b]$.  Without using Rudin theorem 7.17 (using MVT to bound $f_n-f_m$ by episilon/2 etc..) show that if $f'_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on [a,b] and $f(x)=\lim (f'_n(x))$ for $a<x<b$

I started using the fact that $f_n$ is continuous I can use the fundamental theorem to calculus to show that $f_n(x)=f(x_1)+\int_x^{x_1}f'_n(t)dt$ for $x$ in $[a,b]$.

Could someone please help me out with this proof?  Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format...

Comment: @user146296 see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have as another theorem from Rudin that if $g_n \to g$ uniformly, then 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^b g_n(x)\,dx = 
\int_a^b \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x)\,dx = \int_a^b g(x)\,dx
$$
And so, we can conclude (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) that, setting $g_n = f_n'$, that $f_n \to f$ pointwise.  In order to show that $f_n \to f$ uniformly, it suffices to show the following:

Defining $h_n = g_n - g$, we note that $h_n \to 0$ uniformly.  Prove that $H_n : [a,b] \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
H_n(t) = \int_0^t h_n(t)\,dt
$$
converges to $0$ uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

$f_n(x)=\int_{x_1}^xf'_n(t)dt$, then $f_n(x)-f_m(x)=\int_{x_1}^x(f'_n(t)-f'_n(t))dt$. Hence
$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=|\int_{x_1}^x(f'_n(t)-f'_n(t))dt|\leq |x-x_1|\|f_n'-f_m'\|\leq (b-a)\|f_n'-f_m'\|$$.
We get $$\|f_n-f_m\|\leq (b-a)\|f_n'-f_m'\|$$

Now you can start with your $\varepsilon$...

Comment: I'm not supposed to use this method as the proof though. what other way can you approach this proof other than using the Mean Value Theorem?