# $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to some function $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If we let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions on $[a,b]$ such that,

-there exists a point $x_0\in[a,b]$ where $lim_{n->\infty}f_n(x_0)$ exists
-each $f_n$ is differentiable
-the sequence $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

I want to prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to some function $f$

My logic:

if I use the triangle inequality to write,

$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<=|(f_n(x)-f_m(x))-(f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0))|+|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)|$$

Then I can try and apply the mean value theorem to the first term on the left hand side to prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to some function $f$.

The mean value theorem states,

Suppose f(x) is a function that satisfies both of the following conditions,

-$f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$
-$f(x)$ is differentiable on the open interbal $(a,b)$

Then there is a number $c$ such that $a<c<b$ and,

$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

Comment: Are you hoping to stick to the derivative only, or are you willing to use the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @UmbertoP. the fundamental theorem of calculus was my other option, but I wasn't quite sure how to use it. But would appreciate a answer using the fundamental theorem of calc

Comment: This has been asked here many times. See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951389/show-that-if-f-n-converges-uniformly-on-a-b-then-f-n-converges-uniforml?rq=1

Comment: it doesn't deem like it uses the fundamental theorem of calculus in that link, thanks for the post though

Comment: Did you read the first answer?

Comment: Prove that $H_n : [a,b] \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
H_n(t) = \int_0^t h_n(t)\,dt
$$
converges to $0$ uniformly. how do I prove this part?

Comment: There is no question here. You say you want to do something. What is stopping you from doing it? What exactly is your question?

Comment: @zhw I was given a tip that that might be the way to solve it but not sure how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let's follow through a bit on the approach you described (which seems like an excellent idea to me). As you said, for any $x\in [a,b],$

$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le |(f_n(x)-f_m(x))-(f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0))|+|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)|.$$

Apply the MVT to see the right side above  can be written

$$|(f_n-f_m)'(c)(x-x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)| \le \sup_{[a,b]}|f_n'-f_m'|(b-a)+|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)|.$$

You are now set up to use the "uniformly Cauchy" criterion for uniform convergence.

Comment: thanks for your submission, and why the right hand side? not the left hand side. and finally how do I apply the uniformly Cauchy criterin for uniform convergence? I know that it states that $f_n$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ if and only if for every $\in$ there exists an $N$ such that $m>N$ and $n>N$ implies that $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<\in$

Comment: How could you even apply the MVT to the left side?

Comment: yes you are correct, so how would I now use the uniformly Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence